# How to derive (7.1-15) in 3GPP TR 38.900 V14.3.1?

Tags: coordinate-systems, spherical-coordinates

Recently, I am reading a technical report: 3GPP TR 38.900 V14.3.1 [1]. I want to derive the equation (7.1-15) on page 18 in [1], which is
$$
\psi = \arg ((\sin \gamma \cos \theta \sin(\phi - \alpha) + \cos \gamma (\cos \beta \sin \theta - \sin \beta \cos \theta \cos(\phi - \alpha))) \\
+ j(\sin \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) + \sin \beta \cos \gamma \sin(\phi - \alpha))),
\tag{1}
$$
where $\psi$ is the angle between $\hat{\theta}$ and $\hat{\theta'}$. $\hat{\theta}$ represents the spherical unit vectors of the Global Coordinate System (GCS) and $\hat{\theta'}$ is the representation in the Local Coordinate System (LCS). $\alpha$ is called the bearing angle, $\beta$ is called the downtilt angle and $\gamma$ is called the slant angle. $\theta$ is the zenith angle and $\phi$ is the azimuth angle in a Cartesian coordinate system.

For the further introduction to GCS and LCS, please see Section 7.1 in [1].

**Question**

How to derive (7.1-15) in [1]?

**Reference**

[1] 3GPP TR 38.900 V14.3.1. URL: http://www.3gpp.org/ftp//Specs/archive/38_series/38.900/38900-e31.zip.

---

The following is my attempt to solve the question: From (7.1-12) in [1] we know
$$\psi = \arg(\hat{\theta}(\theta, \phi)^T R \hat{\theta'}(\theta', \phi') + j \hat{\phi}(\theta, \phi)^T R \hat{\theta'}(\theta', \phi')). \tag{2} $$ First, we consider the real part in $\arg(\cdot)$:
$$\hat{\theta}(\theta, \phi)^T R \hat{\theta'}(\theta', \phi') \tag{3}.$$ From (7.1-13) in [1] we know
$$
\hat{\theta} = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos \theta \cos \phi \\
\cos \theta \sin \phi \\
-\sin \theta
\end{matrix} \right]. \tag{4}
$$
As for the matrix $R$, please see (7.1-2) in [1]. Moreover,
$$
\hat{\theta'}(\theta', \phi') = \left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos \theta' \cos \phi' \\
\cos \theta' \sin \phi' \\
-\sin \theta'
\end{matrix} \right]. \tag{5}
$$
From (7.1-1) in [1] we get
$$
\begin{align}
\cos \theta' & = \cos (\text{acos} (\cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin(\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta)) \\
& = \cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos(\phi-\alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin(\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta, \tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
where acos is arccos.

On the other hand, from (7.1-8) in [1] we get
$$
\begin{align}
\cos \phi' = &\cos (\arg ((\cos \beta \sin \theta \cos(\phi - \alpha) - \sin \beta \cos \theta) \\
& + j (\cos \beta \sin \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \sin \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) \\
& + \cos \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta))). \tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
[image: a triangular]

Let
$$
a = \cos \beta \sin \theta \cos(\phi - \alpha) - \sin \beta \cos \theta \tag{8}
$$
and
$$
b = \cos \beta \sin \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \sin \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) + \cos \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta \tag{9}
,$$ then
$$
\begin{align}
(7) & = \cos(\arg(a+jb)) \\
& = \frac{a}{c} \\
& = \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\
& = \frac{\cos \beta \sin \theta \cos(\phi - \alpha) - \sin \beta \cos \theta}{\sqrt{[\cos \beta \sin \theta \cos(\phi - \alpha) - \sin \beta \cos \theta]^2 + [\cos \beta \sin \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \sin \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) + \cos \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta]^2}}. \tag{10}
\end{align}
$$

On the other hand,
$$
\begin{align}
\sin \phi' & = \frac{b}{c} \\
& = \frac{\cos \beta \sin \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \sin \gamma \cos(\phi - \alpha) + \cos \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta}{c}, \tag{11}
\end{align}
$$
where $c$ is the denominator of (10). Then
$$
- \sin \theta' = \pm \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta'}. \tag{12}
$$
Because $\theta' \in [0, \pi]$, $\sin \theta' \geq 0$ and $- \sin \theta' \leq 0$. So
$$
- \sin \theta' = - \sqrt{1 - \cos^2 \theta'}. \tag{13}
$$

Substituting (6) into (13), we can get
$$
\begin{align}
& - \sin \theta' \\ = & - \sqrt{1- [\cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos(\phi-\alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin(\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta]^2}.
\tag{14}
\end{align}
$$

Substituting (4), (7.1-2) in [1], and (5) into (3), we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
(3) = &
\left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos \theta \cos \phi \\
\cos \theta \sin \phi \\
-\sin \theta
\end{matrix} \right]^T \\
&
\left[ \begin{matrix}
\cos \alpha \cos \beta & \cos \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma - \sin \alpha \cos \gamma & \cos \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma + \sin \alpha \sin \gamma
\\
\sin \alpha \cos \beta & \sin \alpha \sin \beta \sin \gamma + \cos \alpha \cos \gamma & \sin \alpha \sin \beta \cos \gamma - \cos \alpha \sin \gamma
\\
- \sin \beta & \cos \beta \sin \gamma & \cos \beta \cos \gamma
\end{matrix} \right]
\\
&
\left[ \begin{matrix}
[ \cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos (\phi - \alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta] a / c \\
[ \cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos (\phi - \alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta] b / c \\
- \sqrt{1 - [ \cos \beta \cos \gamma \cos \theta + (\sin \beta \cos \gamma \cos (\phi - \alpha) - \sin \gamma \sin (\phi - \alpha)) \sin \theta]^2}
\end{matrix} \right].
\tag{15}
\end{align}
$$
Then I do not know how to continue. Any comments or answers are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried contacting the authors? I see they've only got a French telephone number there, but since the document is in English, so even if you don't speak French, you should be able to get a hold of some one who can respond to your inquiry.

Comment: @NauticalMile OK, I understand. Thank you for your suggestion.